# Taking time off to deal with a family emergency

Tags: leave-of-absence

A close relative is in really bad condition. I can't show up to work for the next few days.

I am planning on emailing my supervisor right now and informing him that I cannot be at work next week.

When dealing with a family emergency like this, what is the appropriate way to approach my supervisor to inform them of the time off, and ask about any requirements to justify the time off?

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]! I think you have a good question here, but to make sure it doesn't get closed I'm going to make a small [edit]. If you think it can be improved, or that it doesn't match what you're asking, feel free to [edit] yourself as well. Welcome again, and thanks in advance!

Comment: You got to do what you got to do. Just go and call your boss and explain to him later.

Comment: Tell your superviser exactly what you told us, there's no need or use for beeing subtle or lying. It's a genuine emergency and any respectable superviser would understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my experience this is just life and most people are reasonable because you have to deal with a family emergency. Just pop in ask for some emergency time off. Tell them that you really need to sort this as time is of the essence.

Edit: Sorry I misunderstood. Since you're leaving earlier - I'd call him if I had his number, but if not then email him.

I would say:

> (Person's name)
>
> I'm sorry for such short notice, I've just received news of car accident involving a close relative in (location). I really need leave right away now to assist them and I'll be back on xxx/xxx/xxx. if you need further info my contact details during the next two days will be: .......
>
> I'll contact you as soon as I have more info.
>   (your name)

in essence just be direct and tell him the details he needs.

Comment: wait, pop in? I plan on tomorrow early morning, I won't have time to make a detour to work. That's why I was planning on emailing my supervisor right now but I don't know what to say in the email.

Comment: IT is far better to call than email if you have the phone number.

Answer (score 3):

You should of course follow @preet-sangha's answer and send a nice mail explaining the situation. Just know that he/she is under no legal obligation to accept this, and could even fire you for not showing up to your job. This is not reasonable or likely; it borders on the insane to refuse this to an employee. However, the law does give him/her that power.

Therefore, just for completeness:

In Belgium, there are some situations where your employer cannot deny you vacation time. When a family member dies, or when you get married. The complete list is below, and it is highly likely that other countries have similar laws (link in [Dutch](http://www.jobat.be/nl/artikels/wat-is-klein-verlet/)):

> Death of a spouse or child: 3 days
>
> Death of a close family member: 2 days
>
> Death of a family member: 1 day (the funeral)
>
> Marriage (your own): 2 days
>
> Marriage (of a close family member): 1 day
>
> Holy confirmation (growing-up ritual of your child): 1 day
>
> Civic duty: as much as is required
>
> Inauguration as priest of a close family member: 1 day
>
> Recruitment into the army, or as a conscientious objector: as much time as required
>
> Going to the peace court: 1 day
>
> Civic duty as a juror: as much time as required
>
> Taking care of a sick family member: min. 1 month, max. 3 months

Anything else **can** be refused by your employer, but would certainly stress the professional relationship you have.