# Manager thinks I am lying about a family emergency due to a misunderstanding

Tags: communication, manager, death

One evening at work, I got to know my grandmother was not doing well. I told this to my immediate manager. He misunderstood this to mean she passed away, which I did not know then. Four days later, she has now actually passed away leading my manager to think I am claiming she passed away twice.

He has now taken this to HR. How can I defend myself with my manager and HR?

Comment: [Relevant question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20512/taking-time-off-to-deal-with-a-family-emergency)

Comment: Sounds like the question here is around bereavement time around family members passing.  Manager is accusing her if stating her grandmother has passed away twice.

Comment: @SusanBrowning First off, I'm very sorry for your loss. Your question was just put on hold as being unclear, because it's difficult to tell what you are asking based on the very small amount of information you have provided. Please [edit] your question to add in more and tell the whole story, and be sure to state your actual goals. Better to put in too much information that we can cut down than too little that we can't understand. Hopefully we can get this question re-opened for you.

Comment: @scaaahu Feel free to rollback or make further modifications. The buttons are there for other people to help out.

Comment: @Draken The OP has not provided us with enough info yet. For example, what exactly did she say to her manager so that the manager had such a misunderstanding? And what exactly is her question? Until we have those info, I think a rollback won't savage this question.

Comment: It looks like the OP reposted: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110757/workplace-misunderstanding

Comment: What did you say to your manager so that he misunderstood you? Did you actually say your grandmother was dying? Or something else?

Answer (score 23):

You tell HR: I told my manager that my grandma wasn’t doing well. I never said she died, I have no idea what made my manager think she did. “She isn’t doing well” is quite clear. So what do you want me to do? Do you want me to apologise that me grandma lived for another four days?”

Now if you took a day off to go to her funeral, and then another one, that would be a problem. Otherwise I don’t really get what your managers problem is.

Comment: I'd also mention that it wouldn't make sense to say she died twice in four days.